# How to dynamically disable gestureEnabled in React Navigation?

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview, react-navigation

I'm currently using React Navigation 5.x and I have a modal that swipes downward to close and it has `ScrollView` on it.  The problem is, since the content can be scrolled by gesturing downward, the modal is sometimes accidentally closed.  So I want to dynamically disable `gestureEnabled` to false until `onScrollToTop` indicates that the `ScrollView` has reached the top.

```js
<Main.Navigator
    tabBarPosition="none"
    initialRouteName="Main"
    screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true,
        gestureResponseDistance: {
            horizontal: width,
            vertical: height,
        },
    }}
    mode="modal"
    headerMode="none"
>
 // screens
</Main.Navigator>
```

How do I pass props to `screenOptions` to disable `gestureEnabled` dynamically? Or is there a better way of resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I pass props to screenOptions to disable gestureEnabled dynamically?

Using React Navigation (tested in v6) you can use the `navigation` prop to dynamically enable or disable the gesture on the screen.

```
navigation.setOptions({ gestureEnabled: false })
```

See the [example](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/a87885b4b6c76b7b758f8d07aa6629a820e2dffc/Example/src/screens/Gestures.tsx#L68) provided by React Native Screen.